# Composition $f^n$ is a contraction $\implies f$ possesses a fix point.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, fixed-point-theorems

> **Definition.** $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a fixpoint of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, if $f(x)=x$.
>
> **Notation.** $f^n(x) := \underbrace{(f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f)}_{\text{$n$ times}}(x)$
>
> **Definition.** A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is called a contraction, if there exists a positive constant $L<1$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the inequality
> $$\|f(x)-f(y)\|_{\mathbb{R}^m} \leq L \cdot \|x-y\|_{\mathbb{R}^n} $$
> holds.

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a closed subset and $f : A \to A$. Assume, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that the $n$-fold composition $f^n:A \to A$ is a contraction. Can it be shown, that there exists a fixpoint $x^* \in A$ for $f$?

Comment: What are you allowed to use? The Banach fixed point theorem makes this rather simple, but you might not be allowed to use that at this point.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498109/if-fk-is-a-strict-contraction-for-some-integer-k1-show-that-f-has-a-uni

Comment: @DanRust Yes, the Banach FPT may be used. By that theorem, there is a unique fixpoint $x_0 \in A$ with $f^n(x_0)=x_0$. By this, $f^{n+1}(x_0)=f(x_0)$. But how does this imply something for $f$ itself?

Comment: You can rewrite $f^n(x_0)=f(f^{n-1}(x_0))$

Comment: Aaaah, yes, of course! Thanks :D @Cornman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Banach FPT, $f^n$ has a unique fixed point $x$. $f^n(f(x))=f^{n+1}(x)=f(f^n(x))=f(x)$ so $f(x)$ is a fixed point for $f^n$ as well, and so by unicity $f(x)=x$. If $y$ is a fixed point for $f$ then $f^n(y)=y$ and so $x=y$.